# Is there a way to programmatically find chipset's north bridge, south bridge names and other hardware info on windows?

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, wmi, device-driver

Is there a way to programmatically find system chipset's north bridge, south bridge names and other hardware info on windows ? I don't think WMI provides this information. I'm trying to find out how tools like [hwinfo](http://www.hwinfo.com/) and [cpuinfo](http://www.cpuid-pro.com/products-system-information-kit.php) find this information.

Answer (score 3):

People normally do this kind of stuff through WMI, *but* it fails to provide useful information a lot of times, even providing "wrong" info because sometimes it relies on vendor filled info from the BIOS (via SMBIOS), which frequently comes empty or wrong, instead of going to communicate with the specific hardware part.

I've gone through this experience before to get RAM info. WMI provided wrong BIOS info and I've found that RAM chips comes with a special SPD (Serial Presence Detect) chip that I needed to communicate with. In the end my employer opted for the CPUID API.

Here the CPU-Z author talks a little about this subject in an interview:

http://www.techpowerup.com/mobile/reviews/Interviews/Franck_Delattre/1.html.

To get info like this you need to search on how communicate with the PCI Configuration Space in kernel mode through a driver or go for some alternative API which would do this for you.

Here are some links I've gone through at that time:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35378/Access-Physical-Memory-Port-and-PCI-Configuration

http://support.microsoft.com/?scid=kb;en-us;253232&x=3&y=13

http://www.hollistech.com/Resources/Misc%20articles/getbusdata.htm

http://www.osronline.com/showThread.CFM?link=176210#T4

Also, I think is worth to mention about the SetupDi functions in Windows which sometimes are able to provide info that WMI can't.

Comment: Thanks Chico. I did go through SetupDi Api. Though they seem better than WMI, they are still unreliable most of the time. It's surprising how hard it is to find a decent example for this kind of stuff. If I end up finding a reliable way, I will post it on github :)

Comment: @ivymike ok, I was not in luck with the RAM info, THERE'S WAS NO RELIABLE SOURCE to extract info from SPD chips. I was able to build a simple driver to enable SMBUS for a specific ICH (Intel southbridge) built on my old PC motherboard. Enable SMBUS is the first step to extract info from this chips, I've found some guidance on the linux lm-sensors package that has a module for SMBUS communication and a perl script to interpret the SPD data. Anyway, I've done that just like a proof of concept, it worked based on the datasheet of my specific ICH version, which had...

Comment: @ivymike ...specific PCI Configuration Space addresses. Hardware specs changes even from version to version for the same vendor. I would need to support a list of vendors. This is what the CPUID API does, and also what the lm-sensors package does. The only reliable source would do this kind of massive hardware supporting endeavor.