# How to get hardwares id in java and c++

Tags: java, c++

I want to get hardware ids of processor, motherboard and harddisk from java and c++. Please help me in this. In all oses like windows,linux,mac os.

Comment: I searched few questions on stack but all are only for windows, i want it for all os. Please please guide me.

Comment: Try this, already it is discussed.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986732/how-to-get-a-unique-computer-identifier-in-java-like-disk-id-or-motherboard-id

Comment: @Rajan not really, the OP asks something completely different ...

Comment: check this answer and discussion (notice that it also refers to linux in comments), http://stackoverflow.com/a/11533135

Answer (score 0):

That's a tough topic. I would suggest, if you are brave enough, to use [Solid](http://techbase.kde.org/Development/Tutorials/Solid/Device_Discovery), which is KDE's hardware device framework, which works under Linux/Win/Mac. But you have to take into consideration that Solid will require **a lot** of extra dependencies, i.e. KDE and Qt libraries (some of them), along with the underlying libs which deal with hardware access, so the size of your whole project will increase **a lot**. KDE guys are working, as we speak, to a deep refactoring of their libraries, to get smaller and indipendent subset of their libs, so in a near future Solid will be available with less dependencies than now.
The question is: is it worth to pull such big and extra dependencies to your project? Are you ready to afford the technical difficulties about ship/deploy those libs on each platform?
If the answer is yes, then use it; otherwise, you should try something different (and I have no idea other than Solid), or write your thin&light library which wraps the OS-specific calls to get those informations from the hardware.